# How to check if a string contains all of the characters of a word

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I wish to check if a string contains a all of the characters of a word given, for example:

```
var inputString = "this is just a simple text string";
```

And say I have the word:

```
var word = "ts";
```

Now it should pick out the words that contains <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd>:

> this just string

This is what I am working on:

```
var names = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\S+ts\S+",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

however this does not give me back the words I like. If I had like just a character like <kbd>t</kbd>, it would give me back all of the words that contains <kbd>t</kbd>. If I had <kbd>st</kbd> instead of <kbd>ts</kbd>, it would give me back the word <kbd>just</kbd>.

Any idea of how this can work ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a LINQ solution which is easy on the eyes more natural than regex.

```
var testString = "this is just a simple text string";
string[] words = testString.Split(' ');
var result = words.Where(w => "ts".All(w.Contains));
```

The result is:

> this
>   just
>  
>   string

Comment: Would you know what the syntax is in VB? words.Where(Function(w) "ts".All(w.Contains)) does not compile. "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Contains' accepts this number of arguments"

Answer (score 8):

You can use LINQ's [`Enumerable.All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var input = "this is just a simple text string";
var token = "ts";

var results  = input.Split().Where(str => token.All(c => str.Contains(c))).ToList();

foreach (var res in results)
    Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Output:

```
// this
// just
// string
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this pattern.

```
(?=[^ ]*t)(?=[^ ]*s)[^ ]+
```

You can make regex dynamically.

```
var inputString = "this is just a simple text string";
var word = "ts";

string pattern = "(?=[^ ]*{0})";
string regpattern = string.Join("" , word.Select(x => string.Format(pattern, x))) + "[^ ]+";

var wineNames = Regex.Matches(inputString, regpattern ,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for but, char[] does not contain a definition for select

Comment: @NesquikkM what version of .Net are you using? if  `word.Select` not works try `word.ToCharArray().Select`.

Comment: There we go, for some reason it was not working, but after restarting visual studio the problem went away, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Option without LINQ and Regex (just for fun):

```
string input = "this is just a simple text string";
char[] chars = { 't', 's' };
var array = input.Split();
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach(var word in array)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        if (!word.Contains(c))
        {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isValid) result.Add(word);
}
```