# Match all of desired characters in string even when they are not next to each other

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, char

I am iterating through a list of words and I need to find words that contain ALL of desired characters. I know how to find a substring but that find words that have the characters next to each other. I want to create something that determines if the string contains all of the characters even when they are not next to each other.

For example if I have a string "ent", words in the list like "element", "nintendo", "telephone" would show up.

I currently something have this logic:

```
String textLine = "element";
Regex regX = new Regex("e|n|t");
bool containsAny = regX.IsMatch(textLine);
```

This currently returns true if ANY of the characters exist in the string. I want to create a Regex (or anything else) that will find words that match ALL desired characters. I'm writing this in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: See [*How to check if a string contains all of the characters of a word*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856104/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-all-of-the-characters-of-a-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq

```
var desiredChars = "ent";
var word = "element";
bool contains = desiredChars.All(word.Contains);
```

Comment: Do you know of a way of finding not all but at least 3 of them?

Comment: @EdwinCoronado `var count = desiredChars.Count(word.Contains);` or better `var count = desiredChars.Intersect(word).Count();` :) BTW: Please don't extend your question with new requirements... Consider to ask a new question....